# Change CSS properties based on shiny input

Tags: css, r, shiny

In my app, CSS properties are in a separate file and included in the ui via `includeCSS('./www/styles.css')`.

Is it possible to dynamically change the font-family property based on the value of an input?

e.g. ui contains:

```
selectInput(inputId = 'selected_language', label = 'Choose language', choices = c('lao', 'english'), selected = 'english')
```

When 'lao' is selected, `body { font-family: Phetsarath OT; }` is used while if 'english' is selected `body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }` is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could include the css part in `tags$style` and put it within `renderUI()` on the server side.

The easiest way would be put the rest of the css on the server side as well, but you could also read from the `styles.css` file, see below.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

# Simulating a styles.css file
css_content <- "
h4 {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: #48ca3b;
}
"

writeLines(text = css_content, con = "styles.css")

css <- readLines(con = "styles.css") %>% 
  paste(collapse = "\n")


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'selected_language', label = 'lang', choices = c('lao', 'english'), selected = 'english'),
  uiOutput("css_style"),
  h3("one"),
  h4("two"),
  h5("three")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  style <- reactive({
    ifelse(
      test = input$selected_language == "lao",
      yes = "body { font-family: Phetsarath OT; }",
      no = "body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }"
    )
  })
  
  output$css_style <- renderUI({
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          paste0(c(style(), css), collapse = "\n")
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The newly released shiny 1.6.0 allows dynamic theming https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/theming.html#dynamic-theming-in-shiny